# Probability of two people meeting when the arrival intervals and wait times are different

Tags: probability, self-study

Bill arrives between 5:00 and 5:30 and waits 10 minutes. Will arrives between 5:10 and 5:40 and waits 5 minutes. What is the probability that they meet each other?

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @probabwarrior, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the wiki for the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest drawing a picture. Let B represent Bill's arrival time (in minutes after 5), and W represent Will's arrival time (in minutes after 5). Then $B\sim U(0,30)$ and $W\sim U(10,40)$. Draw the joint region of the b-w plane where they can arrive, and then shade in the region where they're within 10 minutes of each other. If you get it right the whole thing can be done by computing the area of two right isoceles triangles.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I did try areas in the meantime. I get two isosceles trapezoids. I get a probability of ~0.277. Is that so?

Comment: Or try this: Let Bill arrive at a particular time $b$. When can Will arrive in order to meet him? (there are several constraints involved, making one end a $\text{max}$ and the other a $\text{min}$, though you can get rid of one of those right away). From that you can write down the integral over Bill's arrival time (which in the case of doing the integral is best split in two parts to simplify things)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I made a mistake. It's a parallelogram and a trapezoid, and I get a probability of 5/16

Comment: I will look at the near-duplicate, sorry I didn't see it first then

Comment: Without an explicit probability model for arrival time, this question has no unique answer. *E.g.*, if Bill has a propensity to arrive around 5:30 and Will tends to arrive between 5:30 and 5:35, the chance they will meet is near 1. I would therefore like to suggest editing this question to stipulate the model you have in mind along with any other assumptions needed to derive an answer. If the distributions are intended to be uniform, the apparent duplicate explains how to obtain the answer.

Comment: @whuber - good point; I assumed the intent was uniformity, but there's no good reason in the question to assume it.

Comment: @probabwarrior The answer you're aiming for is greater than both your attempts. I was saying there's only a single trapezoid because the "two" trapezoids representing Bill arriving first or Will arriving first are joined together to make one trapezoid (though you can still work it out as two). You might find it easier to compute P(Bill arrives first and doesn't meet Will) + P(Will arrives first and doesn't meet Bill) -- which are each right isoceles triangles.

Comment: In the second probability term there, consider what the earliest *possible* time Bill could arrive and still come after Will left, and what the latest *possible* time Will could arrive and still leave before Bill came. That tells you the size of the smaller triangle.